# Hide imageview in android every 1 sec and display for 1 sec

Tags: android, android-imageview

How do I display `ImageView` in Android every 1 second, then hide it for 1 sec and display it again for 1 sec, repeating indefinitely? I tried using the below technique. I am just a newbie.

```
ImageView v=(ImageView)findViewbyID(R.id.mypic);
Date d=new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("ss");
if(sdf.format(d)%2==0)
    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

The above code just makes the image invisible and does not run continuously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Void Handle {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    boolean visible = true;
       public void run() {
      final ImageView v = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mypic);

      if(visible)
           v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
       else
           v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 

              }
  }, 100);

      Handle();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a countdown timer

```
new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000) {

     boolean visible = true;
     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
           ImageView v=(ImageView)findViewbyID(R.id.mypic);
           if(visible)
               v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
           else
               v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 

            visible = !visible;
     }

     public void onFinish() {

     }
  }.start();
```

Or you could even use a handler

```
Handler handler=new Handler()
    {
        boolean visible = true;
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
               ImageView v=(ImageView)findViewbyID(R.id.mypic);
               if(visible)
                    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
               else
                    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 

            visible = !visible;
        handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 1000);

      }
    };
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Comment: I recommend a basic Handler, it will run indefinitely and can be more accurate. (upvote)